# Is there way to make 2 or 3 or 4 div share the same equal space of a container div

Tags: css, html

This is what I try to achieve: the divs sharing the same space in equal proportion.
With the three divs being aligned at the right of each other.

```
<div>
    <div>
        <p>MyContentA</></p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>MyContentB</></p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>MyContentC</></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm playing with the `float` style and I can't figure out the way it works...  It never does what I want, there's always a new line between the elements: I want them side by side.

Comment: you mean you want them 33% each side by side?

Comment: @Ladineko yes, and wishing not to explicitely set the width in pixel

Comment: @AliRızaAdıyahşi okay, I have tried something I didn't expect to work: I put float:left to all of the three and now it works...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**CSS**

```
.parent {width:300px; height:100px;}
.child {width:33%; float:left; height:100px; background-color:red;}
.child2 {width:33%; float:left; height:100px; background-color:green;}
.child3 {width:33%; float:left; height:100px; background-color:blue;}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">1</div>
    <div class="child2">2</div>
    <div class="child3">3</div>
</div>
```

Example : http://jsfiddle.net/7uE84/

You can also change the child class to 1 class... i just made 3 so you can see all 3 of them in that parent div.

Answer (score 2):

CSS

```
div#container { width: 300px; height: 100px; }

div#container > div { float: left; width: 33%; height: 100%; }

/* Optional coloring */

div#one   { background: #ff0000; }

div#two   { background: #00ff00; }

div#three { background: #0000ff; }
```

HTML

```
<div id="container">

    <div id="one">
        One
    </div>

    <div id="two">
        Two
    </div>

    <div id="three">
        Three
    </div>

</div>
```